# How can I merge my data set based on the time in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, plot, sum

I want to merge the two data into one. But as they are in two different times that's why I cannot just combine them.

I need to add them by keeping the time as it is.
How can I do this?

```
data_1_y_axes=[0,1,3,5,4,6,8,9,7]
time_1_x_axes=[.02,0.03,.05,.06,.07,0.08,0.09,.1,.2]
data_2_y_axes=[0,2,4,5,2,7,5,7,5]
time_2_x_axes=[.002,0.004,.006,.009,.02,0.04,0.06,.07,.09]
plot(time_1_x_axes,data_1_y_axes)
hold on
plot(time_2_x_axes,data_2_y_axes)
```

My expected data will be as follows:

```
New_data=[ 0, 2,4,5,2+0,1,7,3,5+5,7+4,6,5+8,9,7]
New_time=[.002,.004,.006,.009,.02,.03,.04,.05,.06,.07,.08,.09,.1,.2]
```

How can I do this?
[image: This is my sample image. I want to add these two plots into one]

Comment: The plot doesn't match what you say you want to do, you are aware of that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Aggregating Sample Values With Different Sampling Times

The following approach combines the data into a single vectors, `Time_Vector` and `Data_Vector`. Then the `unique()` function is used to find the unique sample times that exist within `Time_Vector`. A for-loop is used to evaluate the indices where the same sample time exists by using the `find()` function. After finding these indices the corresponding values are obtained by using matrix indexing (finds all the values that occur at a given sample time). The aggregate is then taken of this array by using the `sum()` function.

[image: Output Plot and Array Results]

```
data_1_y_axes = [0,1,3,5,4,6,8,9,7];
time_1_x_axes = [0.02,0.03,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.2];
data_2_y_axes = [0,2,4,5,2,7,5,7,5];
time_2_x_axes = [0.002,0.004,0.006,0.009,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.07,0.09];


Data_Vector = [data_1_y_axes data_2_y_axes];
Time_Vector = [time_1_x_axes time_2_x_axes];

Unique_Times = unique(Time_Vector);
for Sample_Index = 1: length(Unique_Times)
    Time_Value = Unique_Times(Sample_Index);
    Indices_With_Matching_Time = find(Time_Vector == Time_Value);
    Output_Data(Sample_Index) = sum(Data_Vector(Indices_With_Matching_Time));
end

plot(Unique_Times,Output_Data);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it without using a for loop. This will run much faster:

```
data_1_y_axes=[0,1,3,5,4,6,8,9,7]
time_1_x_axes=[.02,0.03,.05,.06,.07,0.08,0.09,.1,.2]
data_2_y_axes=[0,2,4,5,2,7,5,7,5]
time_2_x_axes=[.002,0.004,.006,.009,.02,0.04,0.06,.07,.09]

[time_merged,i1,i2] = intersect(time_1_x_axes, time_2_x_axes)
data_merged = data_1_y_axes(i1) + data_2_y_axes(i2)

[time1_remaining, ir1] = setdiff(time_1_x_axes, time_merged)
[time2_remaining, ir2] = setdiff(time_2_x_axes, time_merged)

[time_merged, idx] = sort([time_merged time_1_x_axes(ir1) time_2_x_axes(ir2)])
data_merged = [data_merged data_1_y_axes(ir1) data_2_y_axes(ir2)]
data_merged = data_merged(idx)

plot(time_merged,data_merged)
```

Comment: Awesome use of 'intersect()'. Very clever.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the x and y axis arrays, then aggregate by x-axis values using

- `unique` to get unique `x` values and their indices within the `y` values) and
- `accumarray` to add up all of the `y` values with a common `x` axis index

Using your example data, this would look like:

```
y1 =[0,1,3,5,4,6,8,9,7];
x1 =[.02,0.03,.05,.06,.07,0.08,0.09,.1,.2];
y2 =[0,2,4,5,2,7,5,7,5];
x2 =[.002,0.004,.006,.009,.02,0.04,0.06,.07,.09];

x = [x1, x2]; % Combine x axis data
y = [y1, y2]; % Combine y axis data
[x, ~, idx] = unique( x(:) ); % Get unique x, and their indices
y = accumarray( idx, y );     % Add up y values according to x value index
```